# React Native firebase realtime database not working

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase realtime database on my React Native project. Based on the documentation I did following things on Android side(I'm checking for Android).

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app
```

Then put the *google-services.json* and did all gradle related changes.

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/database
```

I have created a small test db as well to test the functionality.

[image]

This is the code that I have tried on my home page.

```
  componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Component Did Mount")

        database()
        .ref('name/')
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          console.log('User data: ', snapshot);
        });
    }
```

'User data' has not been printed in console. Not only the snapshot values but also user data text. Only 'component did mount' text is printed in console there. I added all the relevant permissions in AndroidMainifest as well

AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                               
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

package json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^12.7.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.7.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper": "2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "i18next": "^20.3.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.94.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-flipper": "^1.4.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
```

I'm using this boilerplate
https://github.com/thecodingmachine/react-native-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

The [`DatabaseReference#on()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#on) accepts two separate callbacks, one for when the requested event fires and one that handles errors.

```js
database()
  .ref('name') // no trailing "/"! (even though it does get trimmed off internally)
  .on(
    'value',
    snapshot => {
      console.log('Latest value for "/name": ', snapshot);
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Failed to retrieve "/name": ', snapshot);
    }
  );
```

Importantly, this method also returns the first snapshot-listening callback, so that you can use it with `DatabaseReference#off` when unmounting your component.

```js
const nameListener = database()
  .ref('name')
  .on(/* ... */);

// create a callback to be called in the `componentWillUnmount()` method
const unsubscribeNameListener = () => nameRef.off('value', nameListener);
```

Rolling this together gives:

```js
class NameFromDatabase extends React.Component {
  private unsubscribers = [];
 
  componentDidMount() {
    const nameRef = database().ref('name');

    const nameListener = nameRef
      .on(
        'value',
        snapshot => {
          console.log('Latest value for "/name": ', snapshot);
        },
        error => {
          console.error('Failed to retrieve "/name": ', snapshot);
        }
      );

    // create a callback to be called in the `componentWillUnmount()` method
    unsubscribers.push(() => nameRef.off('value', nameListener));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    unsubscribers.forEach(unsub => unsub());
  }
}
```

Although the above code works, you really should make use of the React Hooks API and the new Firebase SDK's Modular API instead. Using the class-based form of React and namespace-based version of Firebase is ill-advised for new projects.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, off } from 'firebase/database';

const NameFromDatabase = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const nameRef = ref(getDatabase(), 'name');

    // onValue returns its own unsubscribe function
    return onValue(
      nameRef,
      snapshot => {
        console.log('Latest value for "/name": ', snapshot.val());
        setName(snapshot.val());
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Failed to retrieve "/name": ', error);
        setName(null);
      }
    );
  }

  if (name === void 0)
    return (<div>Loading...</div>);

  if (name === null)
    return (<div class="error">Name not found!</div>);

  return (<div>{ name }</div>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have tried the class component method that you have posted. But still it's not working. Even it doesn't go to error method.  Found some errors on functional components (I think import is wrong ..will check later that)  Can you please check ? I have updated my androidmainfest and package json as well